# JS bind function doesn't get value of object defined using var keyword

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, bind, var, let

Output of both these snippet is different.

Snippet 1:

```
var name={
firstname:'abc',
lastName:'xyz'
}
let pname= function(){
    console.log(this.firstname+' '+this.lastName);
}
pname.call(name);

OUTPUT: undefined undefined
```

Snippet 2:

```
let name={
firstname:'abc',
lastName:'xyz'
}
let pname= function(){
    console.log(this.firstname+' '+this.lastName);
}
pname.call(name);

OUTPUT: abc xyz
```

There is only one difference between both snippets. name is declared with var keyword in 1st snippet and name is declared with let keyword in 2nd snippet.

I don't understand why output is not same.
If anyone have answer please comment.

Comment: Because `var name` in the global scope (browser) conflicts with the `window.name` property. When you run `name =...` in the script, the value for `window.name` is coerced to the string `'[object Object]'`, which (in the `call` method) is converted to a `String` object that doesn't have `this.firstname` or `this.lastName` property so those are undefined. You can confirm that `name` has become `'[object Object]'` by using `console.log(name)`. In contrast, `let name` does not automatically become a key of the window object so there is no such conflict.

Comment: Basically, the problem was not really caused by `.call`, but rather with top-level `var name`, which the window tries to coerce to string when you try `name = ...`

Comment: You can read more on [the MDN page for const](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#description).